# Elasticsearch Aggregation Word Count with using Stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, word-count, stop-words

I'm using elasticsearch to store my data. I want to count the words in my documents. But I want to see the result without the stopwords. For example;  in my current result I see 'and' is my top word. But I want to remove it. Currently I have 3802 stopwords in my stopword.txt. I don't want any of them to be shown in the aggregation result. How can I do that?  MY current query;

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "now-0d/d"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "words": {
          "terms": {
            "size" : 0,
            "field": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The way I want query to work is;

```
    {
      "aggs": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "date": {
                      "gte": "now-0d/d"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "my_stop": {
              "type": "stop",
              "stopwords_path": "/work/projects/stop_words.txt"
            }
          },
        "aggs": {
          "words": {
            "terms": {
              "size" : 0,
              "field": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

By the way, I have my stopwords list in my custom analyzer.But it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: Please show your current query.

Comment: Good description of what you're trying to do, however I think that without showing what you've tried so far, you're going to to get flack.

Comment: I've updated the question. Where can I add stopword filtering?

Comment: @Val You have a solution Sir?

Comment: @JSKNS you have any solution Sir?